# mySQL query: finding values in backup table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: roles and roles_backup.

due to faulty backend code, values from the field `role` have been set to `NULL` (only with certain records).

what i need to acomplish: finding all records from the backup table where role is set in order to get them back.

what is the best method of querying this?

i've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM roles WHERE (role IS NULL OR role='') UNION
SELECT * FROM roles_backup WHERE (role <>'')
```

Comment: If you show us some methods, we can pick the best

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these records have an ID, you could do something like this to restore your roles from the roles_backup table:

```
UPDATE roles
SET role = ( SELECT role FROM roles_backup WHERE id = roles.id )
WHERE role IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks! but how would be the actual query for verifying the records first?

Comment: This query will show the records where role is null from your original table. The third column will show what will be used from the backup table.

`SELECT roles.id, roles.role, backup_roles.role
FROM roles
JOIN roles_backup ON roles.id = roles_backup.id
WHERE roles.role IS NULL`